# Understanding why diffierence of bean factory behaviour during autoconfiguration and dependency injection

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-autoconfiguration

Considering the following configuration class which declares two beans, `bean B` which should only be created on conditional of `bean A`.

```
@Configuration(
    proxyBeanMethods = false
)
@AutoConfigureBefore(SomeOtherCOnfig.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "prop",havingValue = "false")
public class SomeConfiguration {

@Bean("beanA")
BeanA beanA() {
if (someCOndition){
   return null;
}
   return new BeanA();
}


@ConditionalOnBean(name = "beanA")
@Bean(name = "beanB")
BeanB beanB(@Qualifier("beanA") BeanA beanA) {
    return new BeanB(beanA);
}
```

When `someCondition` is true I expect `beanA` not to be matched in the autoconfiguration report thus mean beanB creation is never attempted to be executed.
The behaviour i see is, `beanA` is considered a positive match in the autoconfiguration

`SomeConfiguration#beanB matched:- @ConditionalOnBean (names: beanA; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'beanA' (OnBeanCondition)`

and `beanB` is attempted to be created and as I expect happens the exception thrown
`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type`

Why is the `beanA` considered to be in the beanFactory here during autoconfiguration but also not there either when injecting dependencies?

Is it because the bean is there, or at least a reference of type which points to null null? But if that is the case shouldn't spring be injecting a null bean to beanB

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Returning `null` doesn't make the bean not exists, spring will create a `NullBean` (to support returning `null` from an `@Bean` method) which makes the bean definition exists (hence the conditionalonbean will succeed) but retrieving it will lead to `null`. Instead of an if you shoulduse an `@ConditionalOn...` that suites your need to prevent the bean from being created.

Comment: Ok I understand that explanation but why does the bean definition not exist when its being injected. Why is the particular exception `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` when injected while during the autoconfiguration process the bean definition did exist for it to be matched.

Comment: Because it is a `NullBean`. So it does exist but this case is handled in a special way, which can be confusing. But generally speaking you shouldn't be returning `null` from an `@Bean` method. The `NullBean` is particularly useful when using an `ObjectProvider` and its methods.

Comment: I agree and ultimately I feel usages of returning `null` is a design flaw unless really unavoidable in some cases although I have seen cases of it in the spring framework `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration` for example. Can you provide any examples of where returning `NullBean` is dangerous?

I didnt realise Spring internally created a `org.springframework.beans.factory.support.NullBean` so thanks for sharing that.

Comment: I don't see where the `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` returns `null`? However the `NullBean` was introduced with [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20384) (IIRC).